# Horizontal Menu Displays Incorrect on Widescreen Monitor

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu

I have a small problem with a horizontal menu I have implemented for a website. The menu only contains three items, but when viewed on quite a large widescreen monitor, the last item appears to collapse on to a new line. I can't actually test this myself as the widescreen monitor is used by my client, and whilst I can't reproduce the error they have sent me this screenshot.

[image]

The client is using Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7, and I have tested this browser and OS on a normal size monitor which seems to work. It seems to be the widescreen that is the problem.

Here is how the page looks on my screen, and every other subsequent screen I've tested on.

[image]

Here is the code I have for the menu.

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item" id="first-item"><a href="/why-us.php">WHY US</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/links.php">LINKS</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-item {
    font-size:2em;
    margin-left:175px;
}

.nav-item a {
    color:#2B2F73;
}

.nav {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:auto;
    width:744px;
}

.nav li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}

#first-item {
    margin-left:0px !important;
}

.menu {
    width:960px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Can anyone identify any glaring errors in my code that may be producing this error?

Comment: I would recommend posting a live example of your code, so that people with widescreen monitors and IE8 can see for themselves. That said, there may be a way for *you* to test this despite not having the proper monitor: have you tried using CSS to give the `html` tag a width of `1280px` (or some other widescreen size)? If you do that, there'll be horizontal scrollbars, but the content should all be laid out and displayed the same way it would be in widescreen.

Comment: That's a smart idea, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that they've got their "Text Size" set to "Larger" (or perhaps "Largest"):

[image]

[Your code is here](http://jsbin.com/axibo5), and it looks exactly like the client's screenshot with "Larger" text in IE8.

Now you can reproduce the problem, you should be able to fix it.

I'd provide better instructions, but it's difficult to do so without being able to see the entire site.

The "widescreen monitor" part is not relevant - you're declaring `width: 960px` on the outermost container (`.menu`). It will be `960px` no matter what the screen width is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have managed to reproduce the error which is fantastic, and good enough for me as I can now fix the problem myself. I'll bare this in mind for future developments. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

try reducing some width in .nav-item, .nav and .menu

If this does not helps you, then can you please provide the link where this is been hosted. So that we can check ther and quickly reply to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    .nav-item {
     font-size:2em;
     margin-left:5em;
    }

Granted, if the chrome (the user's browser) increases their text size too much, no matter what it will eventually break if you use ems as they are of course based on the text size.

`<subjective>`
In general, its best-practice to use percentages for text-sizes and use pixels for margins/padding/distances for best consistancy between browsers.

Also using a reset css (like YUI base-reset-fonts.css) is a good idea too
`</subjective>`

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to play a bit with your **width** tags.

What about removing the one in "nav" ?

I'm sorry this is not a question to ask here. This problem is very easy to solve, you can figure out yourself if you try to change things...

My best advice on this question is that you get a decent tool to "test" CSS and see the result "live".
I'm happy with the Firefox/Chrome FireBug extension (but it doesn't save the result, you have to copy&paste it).

Comment: If you read the question thoroughly you would have noted that it actually works on all tests I have done except for a clients widescreen monitor. I don't have access to this monitor, so wanted to know if there was a definitive answer to the question that wouldn't require me going to my clients office and doing the work there!