# IE9 Browser Version Rendering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been using the IE9 Browser Version Rendering to do my IE cross browser testing on IE7 & IE8. My question is though, are the results that these versions return accurate to what a standalone version would be like?

The reason I ask is that I have created a site which works well across all browsers using the IE Browser Version Rendering but I have have recieved a screenshot of the site in a standalone IE7 version that looks really poor, for example the header tags which are basic 24px arial font are rendering terrible?

Regards
Kyle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the IE9 emulations [are not exact](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/04/testing-multiple-versions-of-ie-on-one-pc.aspx).

You can use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to get a way better view (the rendering will be identical, but interactions such as searching, printing, opening new windows will not).

For 100% of the old experience, turn to Microsoft's [VM images of old IEs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

Comment: +1. IE7 is not the same as IE7-compatibility mode in other versions of IE. Also +1 for mentioning IETester and the fact that a VM image is the only 100% reliable way of back testing. Very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my reasonably extensive experience testing things in IE9 with the various different "Browser Modes" to test as the older versions of IE, it's been *exactly the same* as using the actual browser.

I do still have virtual machines containing the genuine versions, because there are (very rarely) differences.

But, they tend to be *bizarre edge cases*, and certainly not something as mundane as the size of a font.

I think you're having this problem: [Horizontal Menu Displays Incorrect on Widescreen Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095308/horizontal-menu-displays-incorrect-on-widescreen-monitor/6095453#6095453)

..which is that the "Text Size" has been changed from the default.